# Why isn't this working? (php ifelse)

Tags: php, if-statement

Can someone tell me why this is still showing the data?

```
<? $info = 0;?>
<? if ($info == 1){?>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <img src="<?= $info['n_1_image1'];?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <b>Title:</b> <?= $info['n_1_title1'];?><hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 10px"> <br />
    <b>Total Views:</b> <?= number_format($info['n_1_view1']);?><hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 10px"> <br />
    <b>Duration:</b> <?= gmdate("H:i:s", $info['n_1_time1'])?><hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 10px"> <br />
    <b>Likes:</b> <?= number_format($info['n_1_likes1']);?><hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 10px"> <br />
    <b>Comments:</b> <?= number_format($info['n_1_comments1']);?><hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 10px"> <br /><br />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="<?=$info['n_1_link1'];?>" target="_blank"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-shadow btn-danger" style="height: 175px; width: 200px">Watch Now!</button></a>
</div>
<br /><br />
 <?}else{?>

<?}?>
```

I really don't know why this will show data even $info isn't 1

I hope someone can help me thanks!

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Can you elaborate? Also, You declare `$info` as an integer, but at lower part of your codes, you read the contents of the variable as array. Confusing.

Comment: Look at the html source output.

Comment: follow @Felix's advice or enable php short tags in `php.ini` `short_open_tag=On`

Comment: View your page source. If you see the raw php code in your browser, then the code WASN'T executed, e.g. `<?`-short tags aren't enabled on your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you need to use `<?php` instead of `<?` unless you use `short_open_tag=On` in your `php.ini`.

From the **[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)**:

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which
>   are  which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the
>   code between them. Parsing in this manner allows PHP to be embedded in
>   all sorts of different documents, as everything outside of a pair of
>   opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser.
>
> PHP also allows for short open tags  (which are discouraged
>   because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini
>   configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the
>   --enable-short-tags option.

Comment: This is probably right -  It's hard to see how the cited code could output text unless `short_open_tag` is turned off and it's just rendering the PHP as text. However, you really should have at least mentioned the shorttag concept in your answer.

Comment: Ok, I've updated with your suggestion.

Comment: Better - though it's pretty subjective to say that shorttags are discouraged. Considering that PHP5.4+ treats them interchangeably with `<?php` tags (i.e. no longer something that can be turned on or off via `php.ini`) I'd say that it's a stretch to say that they're discouraged... perhaps just that they don't work on all legacy systems and can be confusing when working with some `XML` documents.